Yield curve steepner or flattener trades
Hi if anyone will kindly help to clear up some confusion that i might have.
Market is currently placing bets on a curve steepener trade due to Trump's potential election success.
Steepener trade is where i buy the first leg（short-term eg 2yr) and sell the second leg(long-term eg 10yr). of cos, taking into consideration of a tux ratio.
when i take a steepener trade, i would want the yield difference to become more positive in order for my trade to profit? since we are in a inverted yield curve now, and 10y2y is being quote as -0.25 for example. so a -0.25 --> -0.19 will mean that i make a profit.
My confusion lies with some text says that a steepener trade is when you expect the yield curve differences to widen.
When we are in a inverted yield curve, widening means more negative. (which should make no sense if we are making a steepener trade as we think that the yield curve will steepen instead of being more inverted.)
am i missing out something?

Widen means get closer to 0. -25 to -19 is wider as its closer to zero  or less confusingly steeper.

and i assume, for a "normal" shaped yield curve, it will be getting further away from 0.(more positive) .

Yes, the English language has trouble talking about negative things changing, but if you think in algebraic terms (or look at the y axis) you can avoid the confusion.

These ambiguities often appear in markets. When talking about yield curve trades I prefer the terms steepen and flatten, albeit an ambiguity exists there too becuase to flatten is for the spread to go down and for an inverted curve this direction would make it more inverted, so as to to say make it less "flat". And for an inverted curve to steepen would make its spread go towards zero, i.e. make it more "flat". :-S
